# Variable in a Perl function has an unexpected value outside the function

Tags: perl, recursion, dbi

So, I'm new to Perl. I'm attempting to create a recursive subroutine. The logic seems simple:

```
sub directory_tree
{
    my $sth = $dbh->prepare("
        SELECT id, org_id, name
        FROM media_directories
        WHERE
            org_id = ?
            AND parent = ?
            AND bucket = ?
    ");
    $sth->bind_param(1, $_[0]);
    $sth->bind_param(2, $_[1]);
    $sth->bind_param(3, 'mfsermons.myflock2.com');
    $sth->execute;

    $result = '';
    while(my($id, $org_id, $name) = $sth->fetchrow_array())
    {
        $result .= "<option value='$id'>$name</option>";  #377
        $result .= directory_tree($org_id, $id);          #378
    }

    return $result;
}

$directory_tree = '<select name="folder">';
$directory_tree .= directory_tree($churchid, 0);
$directory_tree .= '</select>';
```

---

Why is it that when I print `$result` after line 377 that it is equal to the expected value, but when I print it on line 378, nothing appears? Shouldn't the .= operator just run the function again, and then append to the value?

My best guess is that there are some scope issues in Perl I don't understand, particularly with regards to `$result`. However, for the life of me, I can't figure out what's wrong, and I have absolutely no idea where to look!

When I turn on error reporting, fatals and warnings, nothing is returned. What could possibly be going wrong that I'm missing?

Comment: `use strict`, avoid global variables.

Comment: Dude, adding `my` fixed it! I had absolutely no idea that variables were global by default when created inside subroutines. Thanks! If you want to post an answer, I'll mark it as the best answer!

Comment: @choroba, Are you gonna make that an answer?

Comment: @NathanaelShermett: Implicitly defined variables are global ones in pretty much every language that doesn't force you to declare them. The only exception I can think of is loop control variables

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`use strict`, avoid global variables. In other words: you are reusing the global `$result`, resetting its value in each call to the subroutine.